# Specify database for eloquent updateOrCreate

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

So i work with Laravel 5.5, have two connections in my project how to specify the connection to use for eloquent updateOrCreate instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instruction on('databasename') User::on('databasename')->updateOrCreate